# Linear transformations on the full tensor algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose I have a real vector space $\Bbb R^n$, and I construct the tensor algebra $\otimes(\Bbb R^n)$. There appear to be two types of transformations that are useful on this algebra:

1. Algebraic homomorphisms on $\otimes(\Bbb R^n)$, which respect the algebra structure
2. Linear transformations on $\otimes(\Bbb R^n)$, where we vectorize the tensor

It's clear that everything in #1 is also an instance of #2, but the converse shouldn't be true (unless I'm really missing something).

Which begs the question: is there any use at all to #2, or any way to think of it? On the one hand, you can think of it as a bunch of morphisms being applied from the 'wrong' category. On the other hand, the fact that the tensor product typically converts from multilinear maps to linear ones makes me think that perhaps there's some nice, deep interpretation there.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what #2 is? An example would be good, it's not clear to me at the moment of what you mean.

Comment: So if for example we're working in $\Bbb R^3$, with basis elements $x, y, z$, then a basis for $\otimes(\Bbb R^3)$ would be given by $1, x, y, z, x\otimes x, x\otimes y, x\otimes z, y\otimes x, y\otimes y, y\otimes z, z\otimes x, z\otimes y, z\otimes z, x\otimes x\otimes x, x\otimes x\otimes y, ...$ The thing I'm talking about in #2 consists of "forgetting" the tensor product structure is there, just treating the entire thing as a giant vector space, and then looking at linear transformations on it.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't seem that you would get something meaningful that way. On the other hand, if you grade the tensor algebra by degree, and look at linear maps preserving the grading, then you might get something. There is also a natural way of lifting a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to a map $\bigotimes(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but this automatically falls under category #1.

Comment: Do you have any examples of #2 "in the wild" that we could take a peek at?

Comment: Preserving the grading is too strong for most interesting homomorphisms - for instance the one sending $x\otimes x \to 0$ for all $x$ (yielding the exterior algebra). Most of the stuff I was looking at is actually better expressed in the language of commutative algebras, so we'd be looking at the symmetric algebra (polynomial rings) instead.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a parameterization of algebra homomorphisms in the case where the image isn't free, just to play around with a bunch of those, and I was wondering if vectorized linear transformations would do it. But it seems like there are "too many" of those in that they don't all respect multiplication, whereas looking only at those determined by the grade-1 subspace yields only the homomorphisms onto free algebras. So there's this interesting middle ground of unexplored territory somewhere, and it makes me wonder what the nice notation should be.